# Update page in real time with AJAX

Tags: sql, ajax, database, real-time-updates

Let's pretend that a dynamic page that works with AJAX is open or loaded in a browser on different computers ("Computer A", "computer B" and "C computer" as it were), in which data is displayed from a query SQL, enabled for update with AJAX.

In the "Computer A" I make a request via AJAX to update a record in database.

Now, I wish to know if when you make that request with AJAX update changes are uploaded automatically in computers "B" and "C".

I mean that the effects are seen in real time on multiple computers with the same page loaded without having to upgrade.

Thank you in advance!

PD. Sorry for the possible mistranslation Google Translate, I speak Spanish

Answer (score 0):

The technical answer is "no"; AJAX involves the browser requesting information without replacing/reloading the page.  You can, however, have the browser make such requests on a periodic basis, so that the next time it makes such a request, it will get the updates, which *looks* like the updates got sent to the other computers automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may be use Node.js or a web service that allows you to do that.

If you couldn't learn Node.js I recomend you to use Pusher, is very easy to use and give you a real time data using, PHP, JavaScript, Python, etc...

https://pusher.com/